# Rename file by replacing character and overwrite

Tags: powershell

On Windows XP, in a folder of files, I need to rename some files, replacing one character in the filename with another and overwriting any files that already have that name.

For example, the folder contains these 2 files:

```
fileA.xml
fileb.xml
```

I need to rename `fileA.xml` to `fileb.xml`, overwriting the original `fileb.xml`

Using PowerShell, I have this command:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -include *.xml | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name.Replace("A","b")}
```

The rename doesn't work as the file already exists.

Doesn't have to be done in PowerShell, but this is the closest I've come so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the `Move-Item` command instead, with the `-Force` parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem . -include *.xml | Move-Item -Destination { $_.name.Replace("A","b")} -Force
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to filter to get the files that you actually want to rename.

```
Get-ChildItem . -include *.xml | Where-Object { $_.name -match "A$" }
```

And feed this to `Move-Item` to rename:

```
Get-ChildItem . -include *.xml | Where-Object { $_.name -match "A$" } | Move-Item -destination { $_.name -replace "A$", "b" }
```

Comment: You mean `Where-Object`, not `Where-Item`.

Comment: @iCodez - Yup, that's what happens when you use only `?{}` :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I couldn't get this to work though.

Answer (score 0):

An updated example for Windows 11

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination { $_.name.Replace("A","b")} -Force
```

Used in the same way as the other answers but updated to work in 2024.