# Batch script to replace . (dot) with space in file and folder names?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, filenames

I have 100s of folders that have . (dot) in the name of the folders and same with the files under those folders...

Any batch or PowerShell script that may remove those . (dots) and replace it with a space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename file by replacing character and overwrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194093/rename-file-by-replacing-character-and-overwrite). There are more if you search but that one should do the trick for you. If you are still stuck update your question with some code and your specific problems. Questions like this are not well received since it shows you have done no effort of your own.

Answer (score 0):

your query specifies either a batch or powershell solution, so going with the former, here are my efforts at getting the scripts you require.

For `file names` with `dots`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "space= "
set "dot=."

for %%i in ("C:\??????\*.*") do (
   set name=%%~ni
   set ext=%%~xi
   ren "%%i" "!name:%dot%=%space%!!ext!"
)
pause
```

For `folder names` with `dots`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "space= "
set "dot=."

   for /d %%i in (C:\??????\*) do (
   set name=%%~nxi
   ren "%%i" "!name:%dot%=%space%!"
)
pause
```